# What is the suggested file structure for Angularjs with PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm developing projects with Angularjs and PHP. This projects can be sold in the future. So I want to use a file structure that is understandable. There are many buildings on the internet, but they are all different.

Is there a structure you would recommend? Or what kind of structure do you use in your project?

That's what I'm using now, what do you think ?

```
app/
----- controllers/
---------- mainController.js
---------- otherController.js
----- services/
---------- requests.php
---------- posts.php
---------- db.php
----- js/
---------- bootstrap.js
---------- jquery.js
---------- app.js
---------- angular.js
---------- route.js
----- views/
---------- mainView.html
---------- otherView.html
index.html
.htaccess
```

Comment: Sorry, but it all depends on what the app does, and you haven't told us that. Probably for good reasons, but it makes your question unanswerable.

Comment: You're right. My projects are usually for restaurant reservations. But the whole file structure is not found here. I just wanted to be an example.

Comment: There is no answer to this question. You should check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Maybe you switch on a different stack*-platform and delete this question. IMO you should make yourself understood what SPA (AngularJS) means. Don't mix backend & client in one application. Both are atomar applications. And .. don't use jQuery while using AngularJS =)